# Google Translate API server side

Tags: php, google-translate, google-translation-api

Is there a way to use the Google Translate API with PHP (server-side)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking a look at http://code.google.com/p/gtranslate-api-php/ which claims to be able to do this. Please note that a required file (GTranslate.php) currently only seems to be available in the SVN repository of this project.

Answer (score 0):

Want to use Google Translate API with PHP (server-side), you would need to insert "google/cloud-translate" and "google/apiclient" in your composer file, run composer update and call translate method after creating an object of the following class:

```
<?php

require_once APP_ROOT . '/library/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once APP_ROOT . '/library/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_TranslateService.php';

class GoogleTranslator
{
    private $developer_key;

    const PROVIDER = "google";
    const SUCCESS = "success";
    const FAILURE = "failure";
    const TRANSLATE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE = 'text translation successful';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->developer_key = '<DEVELOPER KEY HERE>';
    }

    public function translate($text, $source_language, $target_language)
    {
        try {
            $client = new \Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName('Google Translate PHP Starter Application');

            $client->setDeveloperKey($this->developer_key);
            $service = new \Google_TranslateService($client);

            $optional_parameters = array('source' => $source_language);

            $translated_text = $service->translations->listTranslations($text, $target_language, $optional_parameters);
            return array('translation' => $translated_text['translations'][0]['translatedText'],
                'provider' => self::PROVIDER,
                'status' => self::SUCCESS,
                'message' => self::TRANSLATE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage() . " FOR GET TRANSLATION CALL", "GOOGLE TRANSLATE API");
            $res = array('translation' => '',
                'provider' => self::PROVIDER,
                'status' => self::FAILURE,
                'message' => $e->getMessage());
            return $res;
        }
    }
}
```